# Why does the use of functions defined in outer scope not break referential transparency?

Tags: haskell, referential-transparency

I am learning Haskell. If I understand correctly, a simple function in Haskell is always referentially transparent. I thought it means its output depends only on the arguments passed to it.

But a function `f` can call another function `g`, defined in the outer scope. So in that sense, `f`'s return value depends on the definition of `g`. And the function `g` is not passed to `f` as a parameter - at least not explicitly. Doesn't this break referential transparency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referential transparency means that

```
f s = "Hello " ++ g s
g s = s ++ "!"
```

is indistinguishable from

```
f s = "Hello " ++ h s
  where h s = s ++ "!"
g s = s ++ "!"
```

and

```
f s = "Hello " ++ s ++ "!"
g s = s ++ "!"
```

It means you can inline `g` into `f` without it altering the meaning of `f`.

If it was going to alter the meaning of `f`, you would have to alter `g` somehow. How?

Comment: Can't function `g` be redefined in runtime? Sorry I didn't learn enough Haskell yet to know that.

Comment: Nothing can be redefined at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

The key is *immutability*.

I'll illustrate the point by comparison with a language that allows mutability by default - Javascript. Consider the following code:

```
f = function(x) {
    return x;
}

g = function(y) {
    f = function(x) {
        return x+y;
    }
}
```

Now you can break referential transparency:

```
f(1)   -- returns 1
g(10)
f(1)   -- returns 11
```

We don't have referential transparency because you can't replace calls to `f` with their value. For example, in the code

```
console.log(f(1))
g(10)
console.log(f(1))
```

You might imagine that you can replace both calls to `f(1)` with their value (`1`), getting

```
console.log(1)
g(10)
console.log(1)
```

i.e. a piece of code that outputs `1` to the console twice. But actually, running the original code outputs `1` and then outputs `11`, because of the intervening call to `g(10)`.

This isn't possible in Haskell, because all values are immutable. In other words, in Haskell you can't write the function `g` which modifies the value of another function outside its scope. In Haskell, you can always replace function calls with their value without breaking your code.

Answer (score 4):

If `g` is not passed as a parameter, then it is a "top-level declaration". And such declarations cannot change at run-time. The only way they can change is if you recompile the program.

Thus, the only way a function can yield a different result at run-time is if its declared inputs change. It "depends on" several other things, but none of these other things can change at run-time.